# Google App Engine gets a 502 error in the client

Tags: java, google-app-engine, error-handling

We have an API with Googe App Engine. The process does as follows. We have two calls to datastore with objetify and a call with urlfetch (to an external API).

We were working normally and suddenly we started to get in the client some 502 errors. There is not error traces in the server. The message we are getting is this one:

[image]

Do you have any idea of what is happening??? The only change we made was to release the project with different versions, we did it because somebody in Google support recommended us to do it.

Does it mean that GAE is doing some internal maintenance? if so, shouldn't they tell us in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We talked to Google support. They told us that these errors are unpredictable and expected (if they are in a very small percentage, less than 0.01%). They suggested to do an exponential back-off and retry the request.

The reason why this happened was due to a network connectivity loss for a single machine in Google's wide cluster.